# c++: when is a temporary object destructed

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

There are some cases:
case 1:

```
string("test");
int i = 1;
```

This is a temporary object. It will be destructed as soon as we arrive `int i = 1;`. Am I right?

case 2:

```
const char * p = string("test").c_str();
int i = 1;
cout<< p;
```

I think p will point an illegal memory when we arrive `int i = 1;`. But I can always `cout` the right string. I'm just lucky or p is NOT illegal?

case 3:

```
void fun()
{
    throw Exception("error");
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        fun();
    }catch(const Exception & e)
    {
        cout << e.description();
    }
}
```

Can we `throw` a temporary object in a function and catch it at its higher-level function with a const reference?

Comment: You know, you can easily check all those cases by simply implementing those and then debugging the application...

Comment: @rbaleksandar Not really. You might end up with something that seems to work for your particular compiler and runtime but is actually  undefined  behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both case 1 and 2, the temporary object is destructed once the full expression it is in has been evaluated. In case 1 it's when the statement ends.

And in case 2, no you're not lucky, it's *undefined behavior* and that it *seems* to be working is just one of the possibilities of UB.

As for case 3, C++ will itself make sure that there is a valid instance all through the exception handling, and exception handlers can have references to that actual instance.

Comment: *"you have a reference to that actual object instance"* isn't the actual exception object copy-initialized from what is thrown (possibly elided or moved)?

Comment: about case 2, it seems that the const reference can extend a temporary object's lifetime... Are you sure that it's an UB?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That's probably true, I'll rephrase.

Comment: @Thomas Yes I'm sure, there is no const reference to the actual temporary object. It would be different if it was e.g. `const std::string& s = string(...);`

Comment: ohh yeah. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

> > when is a temporary object destructed

After the full expression completes.

> case 1:
>
> string("test"); int i = 1; This is a temporary object. It will be
>   destructed as soon as we arrive int i = 1;. Am I right?

Yes

> case 2:
>
> const char * p = string("test").c_str(); int i = 1; cout<< p; I think
>   p will point an illegal memory when we arrive int i = 1;.

Yes, it will

> But I can
>   always cout the right string. I'm just lucky or p is NOT illegal?

Because in the case of std::cout the full expression only completes after the semicolon.

> Can we throw a temporary object in a function and catch it at its  higher-level function with a const reference?

Yes, you can: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) link has a good explanation of the **exception object** lifetime. I think of it that the exception expression ends when the exception is caught (but that's just a way of thinking about it).